# Calculating charge density

Tags: homework-and-exercises, charge, units, density, unit-conversion

When calculating uniform charge density, I yielded a solution with units: $$VC^2 / Nm^2$$

The answer is telling me that this is equivalent to: $$C/m^2$$

where:

$$m : meter$$
$$C : Coulomb$$
$$V : Volume$$

Perhaps someone more experienced with the field of charge density could explain why the units simplify.

Comment: V would not be the area (you have $m^2$ for that), but the potential in Volts.

Comment: Volts has units $Nm/C$ or more colloquially $J/C$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N=CV/m$, hence your solution turns into $\frac{C}{m}$, which doesn't look right

(electric field in V/m = force in N / charge in C)

I suppose, that answers your question. You can use Wolfram Alpha for unit conversion, for example [in your case](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=volt%20*%20coulomb%5E2%20%2F%20%28newton*m%5E2%29).

And here you'll see how force relates to voltage:

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/elefie.html